# Accessing external server using MS Edge (privateNetworkClientServer)

Tags: iis, cross-domain, microsoft-edge, geoserver

I have a map website showing some layers from another server in a different domain. I can view the map layers from IE, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but it doesn't work when using Microsoft Edge.

I get the following error:

```
This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer
```

The server hosting the map layers is running IIS 8.5, while the server hosting the website is running a much older IIS. I think there's some parameter I have to change on the former (and hopefully I don't have to touch the latter), but I don't know what it is.